# Detect if app is running on iOS beta?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I have some iAd/AdMob supported apps on the iOS app store. I notice every time a iOS beta comes out, ad requests plummet. I'm assuming this is due to many people running the beta OS, and therefor almost always get a iAd test ad. Is there some way my code can detect if an app is on a beta OS version? This way I could default to AdMob so I get some revenue.

Comment: Is your app iOS developer-centric? If not, I rather doubt a significant portion of your user base is running beta versions of the oS.

Comment: Its not developer oriented, its just strange when ad requests drop near 50% the day after a beta iOS comes out, and stays low.

Comment: Think about what that'd have to mean, though - iOS betas require either paying $99 a year for them or pirating them. You're not running a developer-oriented app, so for your theory to be true, half of normal iOS users would have to be buying/pirating,and installing iOS5 - *on the day it comes out*, no less. Hell, I build iOS apps and I don't even have 5 installed yet. I'd say there has to be a different explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a particularly pretty way to do it, but you could read the device version and compare it to the highest current known release version, and revert to AdMob if the device version is higher.

This will get the device version as a string:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

You can convert this to a float value and compare it to a hard-coded version, but this would mean deploying a new version once the new iOS is released:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.3) 
{
    // revert to AdMob...
}
```

As a slightly better solution you could request the current maximum iOS release version from a website... just drop a iosversion.txt file on your site with the contents "4.3" and use that to control the switch.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `[[UIDevice currentDevice] isBeta]` type method.

Comment: Converting a version number to a float is dangerous: For one, floats are imprecise, so depending on what the number is, you may get a different number back. Also, version numbers have two dots, floats only have one, so many version strings won't convert correctly. Finally, even if you removed the 2nd dot, you'd have to pick a number of digits, because 1.10.0 > 1.1.0 for a version number, but 1.10 == 1.1 for a float.

Comment: If you *have to* compare a version number, use componentsSeparatedByString( "." ) to get the version number's parts, then multiply each by 1'000'000/1'000/1 respectively to get an `unsigned long` like 10001001 (for 10.1.1) or 10010005 (10.10.5) and compare that.

Answer (score -4):

According to rumors, the iOS version 8 will come in September.

So, you can use:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSString *releaseDateString = @"2014-09-15 00:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *release = [dateFormater dateFromString:releaseDateString ];
NSComparisonResult comp = [today compare:release];

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0 && result == NSOrderedAscending) return @"Beta";
else return @"Release Version";
```

or get the title of url: https://www.apple.com/ios/ and check iOS ?

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Apple - iOS " withString:@""];
    int version = [title intValue]; // 6, 7, 8...
}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous. Someone may still have the beta installed at that date, or someone may have their date set wrong, or Apple's release may be delayed and your app will try to do something that only works in the final release on the beta or the other way round. Don't do this, too much can go wrong.

Comment: Less rigorous. Time hasn't related to version.